# What are the joints _key attributes names for SetAttribute() function?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

So the SetAttribute() function changed in Gazebo 1.3, it is declared like this:

```
  /// \brief Set a non-generic parameter for the joint.
  /// replaces SetAttribute(Attribute, int, double)
  /// \param[in] _key String key.
  /// \param[in] _index Index of the axis.
  /// \param[in] _value Value of the attribute.
  public: virtual void SetAttribute(const std::string &_key, int _index,
                                    const boost::any &_value) = 0;
```

What are the **`_key`** string values in order to set the following attributes:

```
FUDGE_FACTOR, SUSPENSION_ERP, SUSPENSION_CFM, STOP_ERP, STOP_CFM, ERP,
CFM, FMAX, VEL, HI_STOP, LO_STOP
```

For some of them there are functions like `SetDamping()`, `SetHighStop()`, `SetLowStop()` etc. in order to set them, but for the others  like `stop_cfm`, `stop_erp` etc. ?

Thanks, Andrei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1214/what-are-the-joints-_key-attributes-names-for-setattribute()-function?/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok, figured it out, I was looking in `Joint.cc` not in `ODEJoint.cc`.

The names are:

```
"fudge_factor"
"suspension_erp"
"suspension_cfm"
"stop_erp"
"stop_cfm"
"erp"
"cfm"
"fmax"
"vel"
"hi_stop"
"lo_stop"
"thread_pitch"
```

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0